# QtCreator: Configure default build types

Tags: qt-creator

(Disclaimer: I'm not sure if SO is the right place to ask this. If not I'd appreciate pointing me to a better place.)

Whenever I open a new cmake project in QtCreator (basically all newer versions, let's say 4.3+) my default kit is select with the following build types:

- Default
- Debug
- Release
- Release with Debug Information
- Minimum Size Release

All these options are enabled by default and I have to manually disable them (I only want Debug and Release most of the time).

Is there a way to configure this?

(I've looked through the kit configuration pages and tried to consult google/qtcreator help topics.)